# Querying an unmapped Entity using jpa and hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

I am new to spring,hibernate and jpa.
The problem statement is to hit some reporting database and the records from the table.I am using spring boot to create my REST application.Now the table i want to pick data from is huge and i dont want to create entity for that table as just need to query the table based on some condition and pick four columns as output(out of around 60 columns).I am trying to solve this problem using javax.persistence.EntityManager in my DAO layer.But everywhere i am getting suggestions that to use EntityManager Entity has to be mapped with some table.Is there any way to pick results from table without generating the complete huge entity for that.Baically i want to run a simple native select query and fetch the results.

SELECT new com.xyz.abc.response.TradeInfo(trade.price,trade.ref,trade.nominal) from Trade trade_tb trade where trade.date between  and .

The above query i want to run on database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mention that you don't want to create an entity for a huge table. You don't need to. You can just create an entity that just uses the columns that you need. Based on the query you provide, you will need something like this (note, i didn't actually test if any of this works, it may have some typo's):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "trade_tb")
public class Trade {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private Double price;
    private String ref;
    private Double nominal;
    private LocalDate date;

    //getters, setters, constructors
}
```

Once you have this entity, you can define a repository interface like this:

```
@Repository
public interface TradeRepository extends CrudRepository<Trade,Long> {
    public List<Trade> findByDateBetween(LocalDate beginDate, LocalDate endDate);
}
```

Spring boot will do some magic and implement the repository automatically. All you need to do is autowire the repository and you can just call the findByDateBetween method on it.

If you really don't want to define any entities, you are going to need a native query. (I added a link at the bottom of the post that explains those better than I can) The query needs to be valid sql however, whereas your query has some java stuff in it. You will need to manually map the result of your query to an object. 
By the way, if you do have entities you can use JPQL queries. Those allow a syntax that is closer to your query, and will automatically do the mapping to Java objects for you.

Keep in mind that Hibernate and JPA are meant for object to relational mappings. If you aren't going to use Entities, you might be better of just using JDBC.

For more info, see

https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/

https://thoughts-on-java.org/jpa-native-queries/

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jpa/jpa_jpql.htm

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods

Answer (score 3):

You can try this

Create an entity `Trade`  with 4 fields which you want.

*Hibernate will throw an error only if there are some field added in Entity but it doesn't exist in Database. Not the other way around.

Now you can write a custom query like this and get Object

```
List<Object[]> list = em.createQuery("SELECT t.price, t.ref, t.nominal from Trade t where ... ").getResultList();


for (Object[] obj : list){
    System.out.println(obj[0]); // price
    System.out.println(obj[1]); // ref
}
```

OR

Wrap the fields in a custom object and execute it as a TypedQuery.

```
String query = "SELECT NEW SomeObject(t.price, t.ref, t.nominal) from Trade t where ...";

TypedQuery<SomeObject> typedQuery = em.createQuery(query , SomeObject.class);

List<SomeObject> results = typedQuery.getResultList();
```

Answer (score 1):

With custom entity manager query, you can directly query the table which returns ResultSet.

Get the EntityManager from SpringBoot context.

```
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager entityManager;

Query query = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT trade.price,trade.ref,trade.nominal FROM trade_table trade");
List<TradeDO[]> tradeRows = query.getResultList();
```

For each TradeDO, the order of properties corresponds to SELECT parameter order.